# Firebase validation rule to check if movie with same title already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new to Firebase. I'm making an application which search movies and saves them in the Real Time Database. The data to save follows the below structure:

```
var movieData = {
    title: "Frozen",
    genre: "Animation"
};
```

I save the movie this way:

`database.ref().child("movies").push(movieData);`

This works OK. The problem arises if I try to save it twice so, in my database I'd have the movie duplicated:

```
{
  "movies" : {
    "-LYSENT90rjBj_fIAHpY" : {
      "genre" : "Animation",
      "title" : "Frozen"
    },
    "-LYSEPufvX3p3w-yXf4d" : {
      "genre" : "Animation",
      "title" : "Frozen"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a validation rule that checks **if some movie with the same title already exists**. My last attempt is this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "movies": {
      "$pushid" : {
        ".validate": "root.child('movies/' + newData.child('title').val()).val() === null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I find hard to understand how it checks for all movies if the `pushid`is different for each movie. Moreover, in the simulator, I have seen that I can only test `read`, `set` and `update` methods.

Is there some way to achieve this? Or would be easier to manually check through a query in the client just before pushing the movie?

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform filtered queries in security rules.  The only way you can reach back into the database is if you know the full path of the node you want to read.  So I don't think you'll be able to do this with security rules.  Consider instead using Cloud Functions to reactively wipe out invalid data, or mark it as invalid, after it's been added.  Or, as you mentioned, check on the client first, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about using like Animation_Frozen as pushid.You can add two string together on client side.

```
database.ref().child("Animation"+"_"+"Frozen").set(movieData)
```